# Checking equality of unsorted lists of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to check whether 2 unsorted lists of dictionaries have the same content, even though the order may be different.

An `in` check isn't good enough because duplicate dictionaries are possible. (e.g. `list1 = [dict1, dict1, dict2]` and `list2 = [dict1, dict2, dict2]`)

If it were lists of lists, I'd just sort them:

`sorted(list_of_lists1) == sorted(list_of_lists2)`

But sorting dictionaries is unstable.

I can get around this by converting all the dicts to tuples but that seems inefficient and lame.

Is there a more direct solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need to hash anything - you can change each dictionary to a sorted list of tuples of key-value pairs, and sort that.

```
def dict_list_eq(l1, l2):
    sorted_l1 = sorted(sorted(d.items()) for d in l1)
    sorted_l2 = sorted(sorted(d.items()) for d in l2)
    return sorted_l1 == sorted_l2

l1 = [{1: 2}, {3: 4}]
l2 = [{3: 4}, {1: 2}]
l3 = [{1: 209}, {3: 4}]

print(dict_list_eq(l1, l2))
print(dict_list_eq(l1, l3))
```

Output, as expected:

```
True
False
```

Comment: This is what I did, but I really thought there'd be a way to do it with dictionaries. Thanks though!

Comment: My intuition says that if you kept them as dictionaries it wouldn't be possible to sort them, so you would have to compare each item to each other item, resulting in `O(n^2)` runtime, whereas this uses a (probably) `O(n)` conversion to list/tuple, an `O(n log(n))` sort and then an `O(n)` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking to make sure that the exact same objects are in each list the same number of times you can rely on the id (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) of the dictionaries, and do the sorting you mentioned:

```
if sorted(id(d) for d in list1) == sorted(id(d) for d in list2):
    ...
```

If you are looking for dicts that might be equal but are not the same python object then this wont work.

Comment: Right, in my case, they are equal but not the same object.